# Target everything but Internet Explorer 8-

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I want to target everything **except** IE, versions 8 and below. Normally, I would use a conditional comment like this:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--><p>Do non IE things</p><!--[if !IE]><!-->
```

However this targets versions 9 and below. Is there any way to only target versions 8 and below, possibly with JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: @elclanrs The only problem with that article is it gets the *non-IE* part wrong (needs `<!-->` after the condition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
<!--[if IE gt 8]><!--> content here <!--<![endif]-->
```

- IE 8 and below will respect the condition and not show the content
- IE 9 will pass the condition (because it is not IE 8) and show the content
- Everything else (including IE 10 and 11) will ignore the conditional as simply a comment and show the content

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFY89/)

<sub>(edit: just noticed you said *versions 8 and below*. Updated answer to reflect that)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in IE11, it ignores conditionals. You are better off doing feature detection, rather than the browser sniffing you are doing. Here is the script I use in my SPA to redirect the user to a core site when they are using an obsolete browser.

```
    <script>

    var ef = "?_escaped_fragment_=";

    if (!('querySelector' in document)
         || !('localStorage' in window)
         || !('addEventListener' in window)
        || !('matchMedia' in window)) {

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("#!") > 0) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("#!", ef);
        } else {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf(ef) < 0) {
                window.location.href = window.location.href + ef;
            }
        }

    } else {

        if (window.location.href.indexOf(ef) >= 0) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(ef, "#!");
        }
    }

</script>
```